# I am trying to move my dropdown menu and the links within the dropdown towards the left and i am trying to add an arrow icon next to 'Specialists'

Tags: html, css

I've tried modifying my code and adding custom arrow icon animated codes into VS Code but i cannot get it to display where i want using CSS. I am wanting the icon to indicate that there is a dropdown when you hover over 'specialists'. Also, i have tried using the margin function to reposition the dropdown menu and the links within but i couldn't get it to work so i removed most of the changes i made.

```css
nav ul {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

nav ul li a {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Specialists</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for something like this?

```css
nav ul {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

nav ul li a {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
 /* arrow */
 .arrowSpan {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
   }

   .dropdown:hover .arrowSpan {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Specialists</a>
      <span class="arrowSpan"></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for in regards to the arrow. Thank you!! I am still struggling with positioning the dropdown menu and links so if you don't mind, i could use some help. Thanks again

Comment: to position the dropdown, may use "flex" for the " Specialists " dropdown. wrap it somewhat like this <div class="op"> <a href="#">Specialists</a><span class = "arrowSpan"></span></div> and adding CSS for it .op { display: flex;align-items: baseline;column-gap: 2px;}

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. When i attempted it, the dropdown menu was almost covering the link. I am not sure if i made a mistake in the code. When i changed the li class to div and added in the css the rest of the css did not apply to the modification

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom arrow icon to indicate the dropdown when hovering over "Specialists" and to reposition the dropdown menu, you can try the following changes:

1. Add a new class for the arrow icon in the HTML where "Specialists" is:

   Specialists▼
2. Modify your CSS to style the arrow icon and adjust its position:

   /* Style the arrow icon */
   .arrow-icon {
   margin-left: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing */
   }

   /* Rotate the arrow icon when hovering over "Specialists" */
   .dropdown:hover .arrow-icon {
   transform: rotate(180deg);
   }

These changes will display a downward-pointing arrow icon next to "Specialists" when you hover over it and rotate it when you hover.

Comment: Hm... Don't know what happend, but here is the missing code: <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Specialists<span class="arrow-icon">&#9660;</span></a>
  <!-- Rest of your code -->
</li>